# Function to convert a CFG string to a tuple

Tags: python, string, function, tuples

I need some help.

I want to write a function in Python, which allows me to make a tuple out of a string. If the string got not the right format the function should print "False".

Here's an example of the I/O of the function:

```
Input: cfg rule('S --> NP VP')       # should be the input as str
Output: ('S',['NP','VP'])            # this should be the output
```

> i = str(input('wait for gramma rule:'))
>      def grammarule(g):
>     if i == ?
>         print
>     else
>         print('wrong format')

the thing is that i had to transform the string into an tuple i guess.
but i head no idea how to do that.
Notice that the given example is just a prototype.
By that fact its more importent to get the following structure:
('S --> NP VP')
to
('SS,['NP','VP'])

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: This seems simple. Are you having any trouble with your code? We can help.

Comment: "right format" ? okay, `if i=="cfg rule('S --> NP VP')": result  = ('S',['NP','VP'])`

Comment: as i mentioned that should work for other combination of rules

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines?

```
import re

def convert(text):
    x=re.match(r'([a-zA-Z]+) --> ([a-zA-Z]+) ([a-zA-Z]+)',text)
    if x:
        return (x.group(1),[x.group(2),x.group(3)])
    else:
        return False

convert("S --> NP VP")
```

Best,

Dante

Comment: Please let me know if this answers your question or if I have misunderstood it.